# What type of data storage should I use in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to download 90+ items from an RSS Feed and I want to display it using a Listview and a custom arrayadapter. What form of data storage should I use to store these deals? I could just pass an array of objects filled with strings and ints(the strings are long btw) but I don't know whether this is a proper design pattern in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one method. Download the items from the feed and cache them in a local SQLite database. When the user wants to view these items, you can feed your local database into a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and set the ListView to use that adapter.